# Vue.js - Insert an external javascript file/object in a Vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this embed code from TradingView which represents a chart:

```
<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script>
new TradingView.widget({
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "hideideas": true
});
</script>
```

I am trying to insert this chart in a Vuejs single-file component, how can I do this?

Comment: put `<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>` in your index.html . and put `new TradingView.widget({...` in your vue component's mounted() lifecycle

Comment: additional to @JacobGoh answer, you might need $nextTick callback.

Comment: @JacobGoh it works but it appears at the bottom of the page. I want to position it somewhere specifically in the template. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: That depends on how `TradingView` view works, which I have no idea about.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout :

```
        setTimeout(function () {
      new TradingView.widget(
          {
            "width": true,
            "height": 386,
            "symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
            "interval": "60",
            "timezone": "exchange",
            "theme": "dark",
            "style": "1",
            "locale": "fa_IR",
            "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
            "hide_side_toolbar": false,
            "container_id": "tradingview_id"
          }
      );
    },1500)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).